# Drawing in a Windows Form in F#

Tags: winforms, f#, drawing

I'm attempting to draw in a non-customized (I mean, simply creating an instance of the default form class, not an instance of a deriving class I can create) `System.Windows.Forms.Form` in F#.

I had created a custom form, but I didn't need nor want a new complex structure like that, so I removed it, and it simplified the code a lot; so much, that it stopped to show an image.

The problem must be in the function I created to draw, that is in another F# project. I've created it (function `conect`) to connect points **in the order they are provided**, unlike `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLines`, that draws lines between the points in some other order why haven't noticed yet (maybe right to left, top to bottom, as the points are represented).

Programa.fs relevant code snippet:

```
let pen = new Pen(brush = Brushes.Black, width = 1.0f)
let original =            
    ([|new PointF(50.0f, 50.0f); new PointF(100.0f, 50.0f)|])

use form1 = new Form(Width = 400, Height = 400, Text = "Fractais (Teste - Windows Forms)")

form1.Paint.Add(
    fun e -> // (1)
        original
        |> List.ofArray        
        |> Base.applyFractal 1uy Base.fractalFunc1
        |> Base.conect e.Graphics pen)
```

If in the lambda expression instead of what's written there was `e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, original)`, it would draw a simple line between the points in the list.

Here's the troublemaker method, in Base.fs, across the solution:

```
let conect (gr:Graphics) (pen:Pen) (points:PointF list) =
    let rec usefulFunc (gr:Graphics) (pen:Pen) (points:PointF list) prevPoint =
        match points with
        | [] -> ()
        | point :: remainings ->                
            gr.DrawLine (pen, prevPoint, point)
            usefulFunc gr caneta remainings.Tail remainings.Head
    usefulFunc gr pen points.Tail points.Head
```

And the called (from the form initialization snippet) and relevant methods' signatures, in Base.fsi (I could give you all of the full methods' implementation, but it would take a lot of space, and this is probably for you already becoming a long question to read):

```
val fractalFunc1 : points:PointF list -> PointF list
val applyFractal : stepNumber:byte -> fractalFunc:(PointF list -> PointF list) -> points:PointF list -> PointF list
val conect : gr:Graphics -> pen:Pen -> points:PointF list -> unit
```

For this specific problem, my search results were none. I'd like to know how can I make the function `conect` work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the computation done in `Base.aplicFractal 1uy Base.funcFractal1` is giving back correct locations of points?

Comment: Devias mudar os nomes das variáveis para inglês antes de colocares a pergunta, senão é bastante estranho para quem não saiba português. Se vires código com nomes de variáveis em alemão por exemplo também vais estranhar bastante, e faz confusão

Comment: @TomasPetricek, there was indeed an error (how did you guess?) inside the method, there were two values called `theta0` and `theta00` (these similar probably unrecommended names have a long explanation), used to transform polar coordinates in cartesian coordinates. It's corrected now though, and `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawLines` does work right.

Comment: @GustavoGuerra, agora, com o Google Tradutor, não há tanto problema, especialmente porque este código é simples, e os nomes pouco relevantes. De qualquer modo tens razão, e por isso mudei os nomes para inglês.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one error in conectar.

```
fUtil gr caneta resto.Tail resto.Head
```

Should be

```
fUtil gr caneta resto ponto
```

You're already matching the head and tail inside of the match statement.

The following code draws a line for me.  I didn't have to modify much.

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let caneta = new Pen(brush = Brushes.Black, width = 1.0f)
let original =            
    ([|new PointF(50.0f, 50.0f); new PointF(100.0f, 50.0f)|])

let form1 = new Form(Width = 400, Height = 400, Text = "Fractais (Teste - Windows Forms)")

let conectar (gr:Graphics) (caneta:Pen) (pontos:PointF list) =
    let rec fUtil (gr:Graphics) (caneta:Pen) (pontos:PointF list) pontoAnt =
        match pontos with
        | [] -> ()
        | ponto :: resto ->                
            gr.DrawLine (caneta, pontoAnt, ponto)
            fUtil gr caneta resto ponto
    fUtil gr caneta pontos.Tail pontos.Head

form1.Paint.Add(
    fun e -> // (1)
        original
        |> List.ofArray        
        //|> aplicFractal 1uy Base.funcFractal1
        |> conectar e.Graphics caneta)

form1.Show()

Application.Run(form1)
```

Comment: Damn it! I knew ther was some kind of boneheaded error, I just couldn't find where! Thank you for pointing it out, thus answering my question.